# Gravando no MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou querendo gravar esses dados mais de 1 vez mas não consigo. Tenho 10 itens cada um deles com $posicao,$track,$artist,$recorder vindo do formulario. Consigo gravar a primeira vez, depois tento gravar novamente com os mesmos dados e nao consigo. Com nomes diferentes de todos os campos eu consigo gravar mas fica tudo mesmo lugar e gostaria de separar os dados em 10 em 10 para poder printar uma lista depois para ser acessada individualmente.
O que eu preciso fazer? É no MySQL ou no PHP? Segue meu código PHP que está fazendo essa gravação e espero que minha dúvida tenha ficado clara.

success.php

```
<?php
@ob_start();
session_start();
include 'connect.php';
?>

//esse conteudo tenho no meio da pagina
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['tracks']) && count($_SESSION['tracks']) > 0):
     $traks = count($_SESSION['tracks']);
     for ($i=0; $i < $traks; $i++) {
        $posicao   = $_SESSION['tracks'][$i]['posicao'];
        $track     = $_SESSION['tracks'][$i]['track'];
        $artist    = $_SESSION['tracks'][$i]['artist'];
        $recorder  = $_SESSION['tracks'][$i]['recorder'];

        $order = "INSERT INTO `users`
                      (id,username,trackname,recordname)
                      VALUES
                      ('$posicao','$track','$artist','$recorder')";

        $result = mysql_query($order);
        if($result) {
          echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
        } else {
          echo("<br>Input data is fail");
        }

        echo "$posicao . {$track} - {$artist} - {$recorder}. <br>";
     }

  endif;
  ?>
```

Comment: Seu código está errado ali, seus comandos `session_start();` e `include 'connect.php';` está fora da tag `<?php`

Comment: @KaduAmaral só coloquei pra exemplificar que estou chamando no começo da página isso. Mas vou editar, veja se está correto como estou fazendo.

Comment: Porque é que gravas mais de uma vez? Alteras algum campo para que tenhas de gravar mais de uma vez?

Comment: @JorgeB. eu quero gravar mais de uma vez por que depois eu quero acessar esses dados separados.

Comment: Isso não tem lógica nenhuma, não deves ter registos repetidos na base de dados. Para isso mais valia teres um campo na base de dados que te indicasse o que tu queres.

Comment: Mas porque queres gravar mais que uma vez? É para playlist diferentes? tipo a minha playlist de 10 tem músicas repetidas com a tua playlist?

Comment: Não @JorgeB. Eu quero fazer 12 playlists referente a 1 ano. Cada mês uma playlist com 10 items (como as mais tocadas de uma radio). Entendeu? Ai vou fazer uma lista desses 12 playlist para o usuário fazer uma consulta. Quero usar essa tela dentro de um aplicativo para Android, via WebView que estou fazendo. Eu só vou entregar para o usuário final essa lista dos playlist cadastrados. A parte de cadastro fica comigo apenas para eu poder cadastrar cada mês, semama ou até por dia um playlist diferente. Ficou claro?

Comment: Não sei quem está negativando minha dúvida, mas estou aprendendo e em vez de negativar poderia ajudar com algum comentário construtivo.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discuss&#227;o no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17256/discussion-between-jorge-b-and-fricks).

Answer (score 1):

Visualizando o seu código, parece que o erro está na inserção do ID. se o seu campo ID é a Primary Key você inserindo o mesmo valor duas vezes, gera um conflito de chave duplicada, por esse motivo que não deve estar gravando.
O ideal é deixar o campo ID com auto increment no MySQL e incluir uma nova coluna para a posição.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente seu script não está usando id com auto_increment.

Se você chamar duas vezes o mesmo formulário, na primeira vai inserir e na segunda vai conflitar com a chave já existente.

Então tente colocar auto_increment na sua coluna id no mysql e retirar ela do insert.

A não ser que você trate isto no formulário que chama o insert, mas ainda assim é passível de conflito.

Answer (score 0):

Sua modelagem de banco de dados está errada, **não é possível gravar registros iguais** no banco, eles precisam ter identificadores únicos, geralmente o campo **ID** como **AUTO_INCREMENT**, sendo assim não precisa informar ele nas instruções SQL de INSERT pois esse valor será gerado automaticamente pelo MySQL.

Tem muitos dados distintos em uma mesma tabela, não é recomendável esse tipo de modelagem, **tente separar**, por exemplo uma tabela para **artistas**, uma tabela para as **músicas**, outra tabela para **usuários** e uma **tabela que relacione as músicas com os usuários**. Você ainda poderia criar uma tabela de *playlists* e *albuns* mas isso depende do seu projeto e necessidade.

Exemplo de modelagem:

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for artists
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `artists`;
CREATE TABLE `artists` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'first key',
  `artistname` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nome do artista',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of artists
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `artists` VALUES ('1', 'Palavrantiga');
INSERT INTO `artists` VALUES ('2', 'Natalie Grant');
INSERT INTO `artists` VALUES ('3', 'Skillet');
INSERT INTO `artists` VALUES ('4', 'Kari Jobe');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tracks
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tracks`;
CREATE TABLE `tracks` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'first key',
  `trackname` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nome da música',
  `artist` int(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Código do artista',
  `link` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of tracks
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `tracks` VALUES ('1', 'Breathe On Us', '4', 'http://open.spotify.com/track/1IFs5I1nHXudA3zV1CqQY4');
INSERT INTO `tracks` VALUES ('2', 'Hands To Heavens', '4', 'http://open.spotify.com/track/6NGcTKotjNCfgTyhzL5Cp4');
INSERT INTO `tracks` VALUES ('3', 'Closer to Your Heart', '2', 'http://open.spotify.com/track/0fPjgWjy57cyP4ZihqBBDZ');
INSERT INTO `tracks` VALUES ('4', 'Hero', '3', 'http://open.spotify.com/track/4CbKVDZkYKdv69I4bCaKUq');
INSERT INTO `tracks` VALUES ('5', 'Monster', '3', 'http://open.spotify.com/track/2UREu1Y8CO4jXkbvqAtP7g');
INSERT INTO `tracks` VALUES ('6', 'Rookmaaker', '1', 'http://open.spotify.com/track/6WDhNHrK2xfCzKJQxVhxJC');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for users
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'first key',
  `username` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nome do usuário',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of users
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('1', 'Carlos');
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES ('2', 'Pedro');

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for user_tracks
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `user_tracks`;
CREATE TABLE `user_tracks` (
  `userId` int(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID do usuário',
  `trackId` int(4) NOT NULL COMMENT 'ID da música',
  `order` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`,`trackId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of user_tracks
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `user_tracks` VALUES ('1', '1', '3');
INSERT INTO `user_tracks` VALUES ('1', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `user_tracks` VALUES ('1', '3', '4');
INSERT INTO `user_tracks` VALUES ('1', '4', '2');
INSERT INTO `user_tracks` VALUES ('1', '6', '5');
INSERT INTO `user_tracks` VALUES ('2', '1', '0');
INSERT INTO `user_tracks` VALUES ('2', '3', '2');
INSERT INTO `user_tracks` VALUES ('2', '6', '0');
```

E um exemplo de consulta usando a biblioteca [ConnectionMSi](https://github.com/KaduAmaral/ConnectionMSi#select):

```
<?php
include_once 'ConnectionMSi.php';

$con = New ConnectionMSi('localhost','root','','test');


$sql  = 'SELECT 
            u.username, a.artistname, t.trackname, t.link, ut.userId, ut.trackId, ut.order
         FROM user_tracks ut
            INNER JOIN users u ON ut.userId = u.id
            INNER JOIN tracks t ON ut.trackId = t.id
               INNER JOIN artists a ON t.artist = a.id
         ORDER BY
          ut.order, ut.userId, ut.trackId;';
$result = $con->ExecuteSQL($sql);
$registros = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo '<table border="1" align="center" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
      <th>Order</th>
      <th>User Name</th>
      <th>Artist Name</th>
      <th>Track Name</th>
      <th>Link</th>
   </tr>';

foreach ($registros as $row) {
   echo "
   <tr>
      <td>{$row['order']}</td>
      <td>{$row['username']}</td>
      <td>{$row['artistname']}</td>
      <td>{$row['trackname']}</td>
      <td><a href=\"{$row['link']}\">{$row['link']}</a></td>
   </tr>";
}

echo '</table>';
```

PS.: Considere utilizar uma biblioteca para fazer a gestão de sua conexão com o banco de dados.

**PS2.: Considere urgentemente mudar de `mysql` para `mysqli`.**

Comment: Na verdade @KaduAmaral eu quero criar um playlist que vai ter um nome e data (Playlist Massa - data) e 10 entradas no banco para cada playlist contendo 10 itens (1. Joao Paulo - Nome da musica - Nome da Gravadora). Eu não sei nada de mysql mas estou tentando desenvolver isso. Se puder me dar uma ajuda para gerar essa sql como eu quero seria ótimo e desde já valeu pela força. Estou aprendendo bastante aqui!

Comment: Então @fricks, ali em cima eu forneci o SQL de exemplo, tente criar um banco de dados separado da sua aplicação pra você estuda-lo. E logo mais abaixo eu forneci um _script_ para que você faça a relação entre as tabelas. Tente rodar esse exemplo ai e dê uma estudada nele.

Comment: No [meu blog](http://devcia.com), estou fazendo uma série de PHPOO pra iniciantes. E até o momento só fiz as partes de configuração de ambiente, e estou planejando fazer a aula sobre o banco de dados essa semana, criando tabelas, inserindo registros e etc. Se inscreve na Newsletter que eu vou mandar um e-mail assim que estiver pronto.

Comment: Eu já me inscrevi lá @KaduAmaral